# Sorting a three-dimensional numpy array by a two-dimensional index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having real trouble with this. I have a three-dimensional numpy array, and I'd like to re-order it by a two-dimensional indexing array. In reality the arrays will be determined programatically and the three-dimensional array may be two or four-dimensioned, but to keep things simple, here's the desired outcome if both arrays were two-dimensional:

```
ph = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,2,1]])
ph_idx = np.array([[0,1,2], [2,1,0]])
for sub_dim_n, sub_dim_ph_idx in enumerate(ph_idx):
    ph[sub_dim_n] = ph[sub_dim_n][sub_dim_ph_idx]
```

This makes the ph array into:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Which is what I'd like. Could anyone please help if it's the same circumstance, but instead of ph, I have a three-dimensional array (psh), like:

```
psh = np.array(
    [[[1,2,3]], 
     [[3,2,1]]]
)
```

Hope that's clear and please ask if it's not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would be an example of `ph_idx` in your three-dimensional case?

Comment: @fuglede - it would be (apologies for the formatting here)
np.array([[[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3]]])

Comment: Formatting is as good as it gets. Not `[3, 2, 1]` this time? Could you also provide an example where `ph` has shape `(2, 2, 3)`?

Comment: So, I didn't put this into the question because I didn't want to overcomplicate things, but ph might have a dim1 of length greater than 1 (like the 2, 2, 3 shape you suggested). If so I'm trying to apply the 2-d array. In something like numpy pseudocode, this would be
ph[ph_idx[:, None, :]]

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to end up with a `ph.shape` shaped array, you could simply `np.squeeze` `ph_ixs` so the shapes match, and use it to index `ph`:

```
print(ph)
[[[1 2 3]]
 [[3 2 1]]]

print(ph_idx)
[[0 1 2]
 [2 1 0]]

np.take_along_axis(np.squeeze(ph), ph_idx, axis=-1)

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: `ph` is the 3-dimensional array in their example, not `ph_idx`. That said, some variation of `np.take_along_axis` is probably what they're after.

Comment: That's a new function to me! Not available on 1.10 at least.

Comment: Thanks - I agree - take_along_axis looks like the function to use here.

Comment: @Chrisper: If all of your examples follow what you've outlined, you won't even need `np.squeeze` either; plain `np.take_along_axis` does the job.

Comment: @yatu: If you use the `ph_idx` from the comments to OP, you can even drop `np.squeeze` on `ph`.

Comment: I think OP meant `ph` there, given the actual indices. Otherwise yes @fuglede

Answer (score 2):

So, the clues are already in the helpful comments here, but for completeness, it's as simple as using np.take_along_axis and a broadcasted version of the 2d array:

```
psh = np.array(
    [[[1,2,3]], 
     [[3,2,1]]]
)
ph_idx = np.array(
    [[0,1,2], 
     [2,1,0]]
)
np.take_along_axis(psh, ph_idx[:, None, :], axis=2)
```

This has the advantage of also working if the 3d array has a dim1 of more than one element:

```
psh = np.array(
    [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 
     [[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]]]
)
ph_idx = np.array([[0,1,2], [2,1,0]])
np.take_along_axis(psh, ph_idx[:, None, :], axis=2)
```

which gives

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```